# Rate of change over last n hours using pandas timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I would like to add columns to a time-indexed pandas DataFrame which contain the rate of change over the last n hours for each of the existing columns. I have accomplished this with the following code, however, it is too slow for my needs (probably due to looping over every index of each column?).

Is there a (computationally) faster way to do this?

```
roc_hours = 12
tol = 1e-10 
for c in ts.columns:
    c_roc = c + ' +++ RoC ' + str(roc_hours) + 'h' 
    ts[c_roc] = np.nan
    for i in ts.index[np.isfinite(ts[c])]:
        df = ts[c][i - np.timedelta64(roc_hours, 'h'):i]
        X = (df.index.values - df.index.values.min()).astype('Int64')*2.77778e-13 #hours back
        Y = df.values
        if Y.std() > tol and X.shape[0] > 1:
            fit = np.polyfit(X,Y,1)
            ts[c_roc][i] = fit[0]
        else:
            ts[c_roc][i] = 0
```

**Edit** input dataframe ts is irregularly sampled and can contain `NaN`s. First few lines of input ts:

```
+---------------------+-------------------+------+------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|         WCT         |         a         |  b   |  c   |         d          |         e         |        f         |
+---------------------+-------------------+------+------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| 2011-09-04 20:00:00 |                   |      |      |                    |                   |                  |
| 2011-09-04 21:00:00 |                   |      |      |                    |                   |                  |
| 2011-09-04 22:00:00 |                   |      |      |                    |                   |                  |
| 2011-09-04 23:00:00 |                   |      |      |                    |                   |                  |
| 2011-09-05 02:00:00 |        93.0       | 97.0 | 20.0 |       209.0        |        85.0       |       98.0       |
| 2011-09-05 03:00:00 | 74.14285714285714 | 97.0 | 20.0 | 194.14285714285717 | 74.42857142857143 |       98.0       |
| 2011-09-05 04:00:00 |        67.5       | 98.5 | 20.0 |       176.0        |        75.0       |       98.0       |
| 2011-09-05 05:00:00 |        72.0       | 98.5 | 20.0 |       176.0        |        75.0       |       98.0       |
| 2011-09-05 07:00:00 |        80.0       | 93.0 | 19.0 |       186.0        |        71.0       |       97.0       |
| 2011-09-05 08:00:00 |        80.0       | 93.0 | 19.0 |       186.0        |        71.0       |       97.0       |
| 2011-09-05 09:00:00 |        78.5       | 98.0 | 19.0 |       186.0        |        71.0       |       97.0       |
| 2011-09-05 10:00:00 |        73.0       | 98.0 | 19.0 |       186.0        |        71.0       |       97.0       |
| 2011-09-05 11:00:00 |        77.0       | 98.0 | 18.0 |       175.0        |        87.0       | 97.0999984741211 |
| 2011-09-05 12:00:00 |        78.0       | 98.0 | 19.0 |       163.0        |        57.0       | 98.4000015258789 |
| 2011-09-05 15:00:00 |        78.0       | 98.0 | 19.0 |       163.0        |        57.0       | 98.4000015258789 |
+---------------------+-------------------+------+------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

**Edit 2**

After profiling, the bottleneck is in the slicing step: `df = ts[c][i - np.timedelta64(roc_hours, 'h'):i]`. This line pulls out observations time-stamped between now-roc_hours and now. It's very handy syntax, but is taking up the bulk of the compute time.

Comment: Please include a few rows/columns of the input `df`.  Is the sample period constant - the dT for each successive sample is the same?

Comment: Sampling is irregular. May also contain NaNs. I added a sample above.

Comment: Help me make sure I'm reading this properly. Are you doing an ols regression where x is the time and y is the observation? So fitting a linear trend, where your rate of change is the coefficient?

Comment: That's right. Rate of change is maybe a misnomer. I'm really looking for the trend over the last n hours (eg the slope of the regression line). This will be in <units of the measurement>/hour.

Comment: If a *column* is `NaN`, will all the columns for that timestamp be `NaN`?

Comment: You are creating a new dataframe in your process, which is your bottleneck.  Have you tried .truncate() instead of ts[c][i-np.timedelta64(roc_hours,'h'):i]?

Comment: Pass a linear-trend function to pandas' `rolling_apply`?

Answer (score 0):

Works on a dataset of mine, haven't checked on yours:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import polyfit
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')

# ... acquire a dataframe named *water* with a column *value*

WINDOW = 10
ax=water.value.plot()
roll = pd.rolling_mean(water.value, WINDOW)
roll.plot(ax=ax)

def lintrend(df):
    df = df.tolist()
    m, b = polyfit(range(len(df)), df,1)
    return m

linny = pd.rolling_apply(water.value, WINDOW, lintrend)

linny.plot(ax=ax)
```

Casting the numpy.ndarray to list after rolling_apply cast it to numpy.ndarray seems inelegant. Suggestions?